# Thread start hook in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

Is there a way to run an arbitrary method whenever a new thread is started in Python (2.7)? My goal is to use [setproctitle](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setproctitle) to set an appropriate title for each spawned thread.

Answer (score 5):

Just inherit from threading.Thread and use this class instead of Thread - as long as you have control over the Threads.

```
import threading

class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, callable, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._call_on_start = callable
    def start(self):
        self._call_on_start()
        super(MyThread, self).start()
```

Just as a coarse sketch.

**Edit**
From the comments the need arose to kind of "inject" the new behavior into an existing application. Let's assume you have a script that itself imports other libraries. These libraries use the `threading` module:

Before importing any other modules, first execute this;

```
import threading 
import time

class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    _call_on_start = None

    def __init__(self, callable_ = None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if callable_ is not None:
            self._call_on_start = callable_

    def start(self):
        if self._call_on_start is not None:
            self._call_on_start
        super(MyThread, self).start()

def set_thread_title():
    print "Set thread title"

MyThread._call_on_start = set_thread_title()        
threading.Thread = MyThread

def calculate_something():
    time.sleep(5)
    print sum(range(1000))

t = threading.Thread(target = calculate_something)
t.start()
time.sleep(2)
t.join()
```

As subsequent imports only do a lookup in `sys.modules`, all other libraries using this should be using our new class now. I regard this as a hack, and it might have strange side effects. But at least it's worth a try.

Please note: `threading.Thread` is not the only way to implement concurrency in python, there are other options like `multiprocessing` etc.. These will be unaffected here.

**Edit 2**
I just took a look at the library you cited and it's all about processes, not Threads! So, just do a `:%s/threading/multiprocessing/g` and `:%s/Thread/Process/g` and things should be fine.

Comment: That would in theory work. However this is a bit of a complex software where multiple components/libraries create threads so I don't really want to do this.

Comment: This makes it really difficult. Maybe you could do something dirty. Don't know if it works, but I'll add an example.

Answer (score -1):

Use `threading.setprofile`. You give it your callback and Python will invoke it every time a new thread starts.

Documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html).

Comment: This is not right.  Python will pass your callback to `sys.setprofile` for each thread that is started, just before the thread's `run` function is called.  Your callback is actually called every time any such thread calls any function, returns from any function or handles an exception from C code.